# Remove model from array with angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a list of `posts` in my component that I retreive by using this code:

```
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit
{
    posts;

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    ngOnInit: void()
    {
        this.http.get('/posts').map(res => res.json()).subscribe(res => this.posts = res);
    }

    delete(post)
    {
        this.http.post('/posts/delete'+ post.id)
            .subscribe(res =>
            {
                // delete post from posts, but how?
            });
    }
}
```

Now my question is how do I remove the post object from the array? Example of the array:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Test'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Test'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Test'
    },
]
```

So I want to remove the post with `id 2` from the array, so angular can update my display table. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `post` is an actual element of the array (and not a cloned copy or something), then you could just do

```
this.posts = this.posts.splice(this.posts.indexOf(post), 1);
```

Comment: You cannot find object inside array with indexOf. You can only use indexOf() if you are trying to find string in array or string in string

Comment: At least in Chrome it works. I am not entirely sure about all the other browsers out in the wild

Comment: Take a look at this. https://plnkr.co/edit/Q8by0XrwCZFNAfbJBj9E?p=preview

Comment: This is not an example of `an actual element of the array` but rather you create a new object resembling one of the objects of the array (which is not the same object)

Comment: I won't ... why should I? I think you didn't get it

Comment: Yea i did, if the comparing object is a reference from the array it self, than indexOf() is possible, but this is not possible the externally made one.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to loop through the list of posts and remove the one you want:

```
delete(post)
{
    this.http.post('/posts/delete'+ post.id)
         .subscribe(res =>
         {
              for(let p in this.posts) {
                   if(this.posts[p].id == post.id) {
                        this.posts.splice(p, 1);
                        break;
                   }
              }
         });
}
```

Or there is solution to use .filter():

```
delete(post)
{
    this.http.post('/posts/delete'+ post.id)
        .subscribe(res =>
         {

             this.posts = this.posts.filter(item => {
                  return item.id != post.id;
             })
        });
    }
```